# Phonegap , Barcode Scanner not working on android

Tags: phonegap-plugins, sencha-touch-2.2

I have done the following to install and use the barcode scanner.

```
>phonegap plugin add https://github.com/jonathannaguin/BarcodeScanner
```

this successfully installed the barcode scanner plugin in the phonegap/plugins directory.

Then i built it for android like this

```
phonegap build android
```

This also finished successfully. Then i placed this in a sencha touch app using a handler on a text field. But when the field is tapped there is no result. Nothing happens.

```
Ext.define("Tasks.view.BarcodeField", {
extend: 'Ext.Container',
alias:'widget.barcodeField',

xtype: 'barcodefield',

config: {    
    layout: 'hbox',
    id: 'barcodeField',
    itemId: 'barcodeField',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            label: 'Barcode',
            labelWidth: '37.4%',                            
            flex: 4        
        },
        {
            xtype: 'image',
            id : 'barcodeScanner',
            itemId : 'barcodeScanner',
            src: 'resources/images/barcodes.png',
            padding: '6 0 0 0',
            flex: 1,
            listeners: {
                tap: function() {
                    console.log("Starting the barcode Scanner");
                    function success(result) {
                         alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                        "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                        "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                        "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
                    }

                    function fail(error) {
                          alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
                    }

                     cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(success, fail);
                }
            }               
        }        
    ]        
},

getValue : function() 
{   
    console.log(this.getItems().getAt(0).getValue());
    return this.getItems().getAt(0).getValue();
},
setValue : function(newvalue) {
   this.getItems().getAt(0).setValue(newvalue);
}
```

});

I see the tap handler is being invoked and the log statement on the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the call to the barcode plugin to the following and it is working. Instead of calling cordova.plugins i used window.plugins and it works.

```
Ext.define("Tasks.view.BarcodeField", {
extend: 'Ext.Container',
alias:'widget.barcodeField',

xtype: 'barcodefield',

config: {    
    layout: 'hbox',
    id: 'barcodeField',
    itemId: 'barcodeField',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            label: 'Barcode',
            labelWidth: '37.4%',                            
            flex: 4        
        },
        {
            xtype: 'image',
            id : 'barcodeScanner',
            itemId : 'barcodeScanner',
            src: 'resources/images/barcodes.png',
            padding: '6 0 0 0',
            flex: 1,
            listeners: {
                tap: function() {
                    console.log("Starting the barcode Scanner");
                    function success(result) {
                         alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                        "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                        "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                        "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
                    }

                    function fail(error) {
                          alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
                    }
                    window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(success, fail);
                    // cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(success, fail);
                }
            }               
        }        
    ]        
},

getValue : function() 
{   
    console.log(this.getItems().getAt(0).getValue());
    return this.getItems().getAt(0).getValue();
},
setValue : function(newvalue) {
   this.getItems().getAt(0).setValue(newvalue);
}
```

});